# Display a series of user selected integers, separated by a comma

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need to produce a list of integers in a label.

On the iPhone screen there are a series of 12 buttons and a label-

(0) (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7) (8) (9) (10) (11)

[***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**]

The user is to click a button, and the buttons's id should then be displayed in a label.

If the user clicks 0,4,7,3,10

Then I want the label to display- [0,4,7,3,10]

This is similar to a calculator app, but a calculator is base10 and its numbers combine to form a string. I would like to keep each integer separate so that other calculations may be performed on the user selected order.

in my @implementation i have tried to modify my calculator app's code, but have had no progress.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you done so far? Post code, please.

Comment: -(IBAction)enterNote:(id)sender {

    currentNumber = currentNumber*10+(int)[sender tag];
    screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",currentNumber];

} //This is from a simple calculator app that will display a sequence of numbers in the screen.text label. I was using it as a model, but it is not working out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons could fire this `IBAction`:

```
- (IBAction)addNumberToLabel:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [numbers addObject:[[sender titleLabel] text]];
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]", [numbers componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
}
```

Since you want the numbers to be displayed `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, it is necessary to change the whole text of the label every time a new number is added to `numbers`, an NSMutableArray you  initiate in your setup code.

Comment: This looks promising, but I am receiving this **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'**  I will check through my connections again.

Comment: How have you declared The `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: Yes. `NSMutableArray *numbers;`

Comment: You'll need to allocate and init it: `NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: I have got it to mostly work. As I click now on the buttons, the text in the label changes to the button id, but the numbers replace the previous instead of being joined by a comma. This seems to be very close. Here is the imp `- (IBAction)enterNote:(UIButton *)sender{
    numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [numbers addObject:[[sender titleLabel] text]];
    
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [numbers componentsJoinedByString:@","]]];
` It seems as though the last bit isn't going through 'componentsJoinedByString'.

Comment: You need to allocate an init your `NSMutableArray` (`numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; `) outside the IBAction, in your `viewDidLoad` method for example. The way it is now, you're destroying the previous `NSMutableArray` every time the `IBAction` is called.

Comment: Thank you, ibeita. Moving it outside of IBAction worked. All is well.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to keep an array (or some sort of stack) of the numbers pressed, and append to the label's text every time the user hits a button. What are you having issues with?

Comment: I tried NSArray, but it didn't work with my ints. My issue is simply implementation and getting the label to print exactly what you suggested. Most of my books on the topic get more complicated than my needs for this.

Comment: You would need to use an `NSMutableArray` in order to continually add objects to it, but you also can't store C data types in an Obj-C array. Try using a `NSNumber`s instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new string `StrOldValue`, and get the actual value of label, in the set to label use

```
NSString *strOldValue= yourLabel.text;    
yourLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",strOldValue, strNewValue)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your things in a Mutable array. 
Then call componentsJoinedByString method like

```
NSLog(@"%@",[pathArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]);
```

You can use any string in place of 'Comma' as your delimiter.